# Unable to put data using find() in IE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am currently working on a project, in which I am getting some data using ajax jQuery. I am using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType : 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,
        //cache: false,
        data : data,
        complete : function() { },
        success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#servicelist').hide();
                $('#stafflist').show();
                data=$(data).find('div#stafflistcontent');
                $('#stafflist').html(data);
            }
    });
```

When I am trying to alert the data at the very first line of `ajax success`,it is returning the complete HTML of the page, now I am going to find the `<div id="stafflistcontent">`. In Firefox and Chrome it is returning the correct HTML but in IE its returning only OBJECT OBJECT, How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit**

IE version : IE8

jQuery Version : 1.9.1

Comment: Which version of IE and jquery are you using?

Comment: `data=$(data).find('div#stafflistcontent').html();` should do the trick

Comment: when trying to alert this data then it is giving `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`$(data).find('div#stafflistcontent')` returns a jQuery object, not "data" (what ever you mean with that). `.html()` takes a string as it's parameter, so that shouldn't work like way.

Instead of

```
$('#stafflist').html(data);
```

use

```
$('#stafflist').empty().append(data);
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to show your HTML and exactly what your AJAX call returns.

Answer (score -1):

replace:

```
$('#stafflist').html(data);
```

with:

```
$(data).html().appendTo('#stafflist');
```

or:

```
 $("<p></p>").append($(data).html()).appendTo('#stafflist');
```

Comment: thanks first solution didnt work but 2nd solution is working for me

Comment: The second solution doesn't make sense. `.html()` returns a string, which doesn't have an `.appendTo()` method.